# ag-grid: using fullWidth row with angular 1.x directive

Tags: ag-grid

I'm trying to render ag-grid with a fullWidth template, that is actually a directive.

```
gridOptions: {
      fullWidthCellRenderer: function(node) {
          var el = angular.element('<div />');
          el[0].innerHTML = '<div directive="node.data"></div>';
          var tpl = $compile(el)($scope);
          return tpl[0];
}
```

The directive expects a model (from 'directive' attribute) but gets undefined.
I'm guessing there are scope issues here, and I do not want to stringify my data in the html template.
How can I pass the data object into my directive?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this in 2 ways:
first is to create a child scope from $scope with `$scope.$new()', assign the node variable to it, and compile to template with it.
second, probably better, is to return the element with no $compile and use 
`angularCompileRows: true` in gridOptions.